# Chinese characters cannot be displayed in mono application on debian system

Tags: .net, linux, user-interface, fonts, mono

I get only empty square characters. Russian or arabic fonts are ok.
I installed chinese/japanese/korean fonts but with no luck. The UI does not display them.

what i did was installing:

```
Chinese (both Simplified & Traditional)
    Serif: fonts-arphic-ukai
    Sans-serif: fonts-arphic-uming
Japanese
    Serif: fonts-ipafont-mincho
    Sans-serif: fonts-ipafont-gothic
Korean
    All: fonts-unfonts-core
```

apt-get install fonts-droid

dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig

fontconfig-config fc-cache -f -v2D

but all with no luck..